# Name of writing style which avoids both first/second/third person

Tags: writing-style, writing

What is the name of the style of writing, often seen in technical manuals and documentation, which avoids using the first, second or third person.

For example, if I were writing a manual on making a cup of tea, I would avoid both of the following

> I tend to pour the water first, then remove the teabag and add milk.

and

> You should pour the water first, then you should remove the teabag and add the milk.

In favour of the style:

> The water should be poured over the teabag, removed, and then the milk should be added.

I am trying to write guidelines on using a specific writing style, but I do not know what to call this style of writing.

<sub><sub>*For tea purists, I know it should be drunk without milk, as nature intended!</sub></sub>

Comment: Your second example, "you should," is second person; *he, she, they* is third person. What you mean is avoiding *active voice* (I/you/he/they/etc. pour water) and used *passive voice* instead (the water is poured).

Comment: @Jacinto thank you, that's pretty much my answer. If you want to post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [*passive voice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)

> The passive voice is a grammatical construction (specifically, a "voice"). The noun or noun phrase that would be the object of an active sentence (such as Our troops defeated the enemy) appears as the subject of a sentence with passive voice (e.g. The enemy was defeated by our troops).